# Why DropDown List show Dates included Time, not just Date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller

I have list of Dates, and in controller i create code for DropDown list, in table i put dates like DATE format, also in model i configurired ad dd/MM/yyyy, in dropdown list i get dates included Time, but i need Just dates in List.

Code in Controller:

```
ViewBag.Datum = new SelectList(db.tbl_relacii.Where(x => x.DatumR >= date), "DatumR", "DatumR");
```

Code in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Datum", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Model Code:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime DatumR { get; set; }
```

And here is data in database:

[image: data in database]

How to take correct data in DropDown List

Comment: can you show the controller code? why not return the model in the controller?

Comment: Question is edited included full controller code, and image from dropdown list.

Comment: uɐpuɐɥƆ - I tried but page putiing down. **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: did u try the below solution?

Comment: Im triing not finished yet, i have Red line at .ToShortDateString(); and error: **does not contain definition fo 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString''**... etc.

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ -Can you read the my answer, i`m banned :(

Comment: See my modified answer - you can try with .ToString("d") if you are getting error for .ToShortDateString(); Not sure why you are getting that error

Comment: Again same the problem. Maby i need to add something in using ?

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ - Thanks i solved i model. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your controller code like below

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        ViewBag.AgentID = new SelectList(db.tbl_agenti, "aID", "agent_ime");
        ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", "ime");
        ViewBag.stanicaDO = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica");
        ViewBag.stanicaOD = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica");
        var tempList = db.tbl_relacii.Where(x => x.DatumR >= date).ToList();
        var options = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(var item in tempList)
        {
            options.Add(new SelectListItem() 
            { 
                Text = item.ToString("d"), 
                Value = item
            };  
        }
       ViewBag.Datum = options;

        return View();
    }
```

And in your view define like below

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Datum", ViewBag.Datum as SelectList, "--Select--",
   new
   {
       @Id = "drpDatum",
       @class = "form-control"
   })
```